# Context of self in a method that is called from a closure

Tags: swift, reference, closures, weak

A method `sampleMethod()` is called from a closure with weak reference of self (`self?.sampleMethod()`), within the same class. What will be the context of self which is now used in `sampleMethod()`? 
Will it be a weak self or a strong one?

Answer (score 1):

Since method `sampleMethod()` invoked successfully, it will use strong `self` reference inside it body by default.

You may think about this line

```
self?.sampleMethod()
```

like this

```
if let s = self {
    s.dynamicType.sampleMethod(s)()
}
```

where you just passing strong reference to instance to related class method